# How can i use Swrve Web SDK in Ionic

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to use swrve web sdk in my ionic project but not able to initialize it. Following is the documentation link

https://docs.swrve.com/developer-documentation/integration/web/#Installing_the_SDK

I have install the SDK using npm command:

> npm install @swrve/web-sdk

after that i use the import statement:

> import SwrveSDK from "swrvesdk";

in a constructor function i declare it as a following

```
SwrveSDK.default.createInstance({
appId: <app_id>,
apiKey: "<web_api_key>",
externalUserId: "<external_user_id>",
});
```

but when i run ionic serve i get following error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'createInstance' of undefined

Whats the proper way for declaring npm package or web javascript libraries?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation looks wrong. Plain wrong.

Try

```
import SwrveSDK from "@swrve/web-sdk";

SwrveSDK.createInstance({
  appId: <app_id>,
  apiKey: "<web_api_key>",
  externalUserId: "<external_user_id>",
});
```

I suspected that they copied and pasted the CommonJS and then forgot to edit it.

Examination of the source code confirms this, the telltale line being
https://github.com/Swrve/swrve-web-sdk/blob/release-1_0/SwrveSDK/src/Swrve.ts#L399

The reason `SwrveSDK.default.createInstance`  looks so suspicious is that the statement `import SwrveSDK from " @swrve/web-sdk";`  imports the export named `default` from the  main module of the package, binding it to the name `SwrveSDK`. Of course it is conceivable that the default export could itself have a property named default but the example using CommonJS  suggests otherwise.

Note that you may need to set `--allowSyntheticDefaultImports` and `--esModuleInterop`. 
Also be sure that you are using TypeScript >= 2.7 or an ES module interop aware loader such as SystemJS.

Comment: I tried:
import SwrveSDK from "swrvesdk";
getting following error:
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "swrvesdk"

Comment: That's a typescript error not a runtime error. Set `--allowSyntheticDefaultImports` and `--esModuleInterop`

Comment: I also tried:
import SwrveSDK from '@swrve/web-sdk';
getting following error:
core.js:1449 ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__swrve_web_sdk___default.a.createInstance is not a function

Comment: You need to import it from the name of the installed package whatever that may be.

Comment: i installed it using: npm install @swrve/web-sdk
so should i use : import SwrveSDK from '@swrve/web-sdk';